# Compile a linux 2.6 kernel module with newer compiler

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel

I build embedded machines that run an RT_PREMPT version of Linux. It's an Ubuntu 10.04 installation running an Linux 2.6 kernel. Yes, it's an old kernel, but I'm stuck with it for awhile.

When I compiled the kernel, I used gcc version 4.4. On this system, there is a kernel module I have been compiling successfully for three years.

From my Makefile...

```
all:

make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) \
    modules
```

My current project requires support for c++14, so I updated gcc and g++ to version 5.1.0 by building from source. All my user-mode software compiles, but when I went to build an updated version of my kernel module, I get the following error right away:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-54-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/tbj/srcroot/ctsengine-hg/CtsRt/ctsrt_main.o
In file included from include/linux/compiler.h:40:0,
             from include/linux/stddef.h:4,
             from include/linux/list.h:4,
             from include/linux/module.h:9,
             from /home/tbj/srcroot/ctsengine-hg/CtsRt/ctsrt_main.c:31:
include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:86:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory
```

In short:

```
fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory
```

If I use gcc 4.4 again (I left it installed on my computer in a different directory), it compiles and runs perfectly.

Obviously, I'm missing something. Is it not possible to compile a kernel module with a newer version of the compiler than what the operating system was compiled with? That seems unlikely to me. Is there a configuration step I'm missing? Is there a system variable I need to update? Are there extra headers I'm supposed to download? I ran apt to update build-essential, but it was up to date. I have the source and headers for the kernel on my system. I'm not sure what else I would download.

Any insights to this problem are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your kernel version is too old and it is missing [`linux/compiler-gcc5.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7829fb09a2b4268b30dd9bc782fa5ebee278b137/include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h).

The header is included from [linux/compiler-gcc.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7829fb09a2b4268b30dd9bc782fa5ebee278b137/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h#L119) and its name is generated by preprocessor macro based on current compiler version:

```
#define _gcc_header(x) __gcc_header(linux/compiler-gcc##x.h)
```

This header was introduced around version `3.18`.

You might try to get this file from a newer kernel source and put in into `include/linux`.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'm guessing copying compiler-gcc4.h into compiler-gcc5.h is also worth a try.

Comment: Grabbed it from here:  raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h and copied it into the headers directory for my kernel. Solved the problem; thanks!

Comment: @abligh You are right. Or `echo "#include <linux/compiler-gcc4.h>" > include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h`.

Comment: Hey guys, I would really like some help. I'm trying to compile linux 2.6.31. I expects `compiler-gcc6.h` I tried copying gcc5 into gcc6.h Doesn't work. Ends up in a slew of errors. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @gideon It depends on errors you receive. I suggest you ask new question giving more details.

Comment: @baf sorry about that, I tried including the gcc4 header into a gcc6.h file. I get `include/linux/compiler-gcc4.h:8:4: error: #error Your version of gcc miscompiles the __weak directive
 #  error Your version of gcc miscompiles the __weak directive`  Also at some point they unified it all into one `compiler-gcc` file and don't have gcc[MAJOR_VERSION] files anymore. Perhaps a suggestion to tweak something into working?

Comment: I also tried just commenting our the #error since I am compiling with `gcc6` However just `make` results in _Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at kernel/timeconst.pl line 373._

Comment: @gideon Seems it won't build with modern perl

Comment: @baf think there's a way to just hack it to build?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

```
$ ls -r /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/ | \
  grep -P "compiler-gcc\d.h" | \
  head -n 1
```

this will hopefully output the latest gcc header suitable for your linux kernel.

In my case it is `compiler-gcc4.h`. Now you can link this file to `compiler-gcc5.h` in the following way:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/compiler-gcc4.h \
             /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h
```